# HP arrray - XP and EVA - performance monitoring

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, performance-monitoring, hpe

I have some HP arrays I'd like to monitor for performance. I'm making a reasonable amount of progress with my 3PARs, in using ssh connectivity and `show...` commands to gather performance information for analysis. (I'm also doing this with my NetApp filers).

However I'd really like to do similar with my EVA and XP arrays and am finding it difficult. XPs have 'HP Performance Advisor' - which seems to work, but not necessarily all the time - we have ongoing difficulties with collecting data from different LPARs, and just generally - our data set is probably too big for the database we're using.

With EVAs, I don't have much in the way of performance capture at all. I've dug out `sssu` as a way of interfacing with an array to gather information - specifically:

```
sssu select manager $hostname username=$username password=$password select system $array ls disk full xml
```

Will give me a useful amount of information - XML formatted, which I then parse for reporting purposes.

But where I'm still having difficulty, is in tracking down how to get the raw performance data out of the arrays. I would very much like to make my own samples every 5m or so, and collate them - without needing multiple different software installations, hosts and tools.

My current approach is using `RRDtool` collecting the raw data and using a web interface of some sort to display. (At the moment I've got something hand rolled).

So - does anyone have experience of capturing this information from these array types, and can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XP is really a rebranded Hitachi USP-V. Performance Advisor is not a Hitachi tool, though, and while it can get some basic numbers, the presets aren't that useful, and there's only so far that tool can take you.

There is a performance extraction tool that you can run on Hitachi machines, but the data from it is very hard to parse. It is badly described in step 2 of [this page](https://tuf.hds.com/gsc/bin/view/Main/RAIDOpenSystemsPerformance/). I think it could be run on an XP from HP, but if the HDS one doesn't work, maybe an HP tech would have a modified version that is designed for HP.

If you can get this thing to run, you can parse the output files and get any information you like, but it's a lot of work.

Comment: I'm surprised that there isn't a cleaner option for this. No SNMP insight either?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure there's no 'nice' options, because I've been looking for a while. At this point, I'll take a binary dump and hand-parse it, if that's all I can get :)

Comment: The USP-V is a shining example of why HDS has such a bad rap for their software. It can be made to be rock solid stable and fast, but managing it is *non-intuitive*, to say the least.